# How to use the "|" keyword in a specflow feature table

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber, specflow, acceptance-testing

I have a specflow table as follows:

```
| ViewableValue | Id  | AnotherId |
| "1 | 2 | 3:2" | abc | 123       |
```

The problem is, Specflow doesn't seem to accept the "|" keyword in the table. How can I escape it so I can have it as a value inside my table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question after trying some things. It is as simple as doing this:

```
| ViewableValue | Id  | AnotherId |
| 1 \| 2 \| 3:2 | abc | 123       |
```